# Deleting necessary data (with checkbox) in React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, delete-file

Need to delete the data that is highlighted by the checkbox. When I click on the checkbox, in all checkboxes the done becomes: true, then false and i can't remove the highlights. When the remove function is worked, only the first element is deleted. How can write a remove function.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([
    {id:1, name:"Peter", surname:"Robinson"},
    {id:2, name:"Ann", surname:"Walker"},
    {id:3, name:"James", surname:"Allen"},
])

  const [check, setCheck] = useState({done: false})
  const remove = () => {
    if (check.done) {
    }
  }
  
  return <>
    <table className="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {Object.keys(user[0]).map((elm,i) => {
            return <td key={i}>
              {elm.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + elm.slice(1)}
            </td>
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
          user.map((elem, ind) => {
            return <tr key={ind}>
              <td>{elem.id}</td>
              <td>{elem.name}</td>
              <td>{elem.surname}</td>
              <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onChange={() => setCheck({done: check.done ? false : true})}/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          })
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button className="btn btn-primary ms-2" onClick={() => remove()}>Delete selected</button>
  </>
}

export default App;
```

Thank you.

Comment: So do you need to implement remove() function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle the `checked` state for each user independently, then delete the ones with the checked flag at `true`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
const [user, setUser] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Peter", surname: "Robinson", checked: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Ann", surname: "Walker", checked: false },
    { id: 3, name: "James", surname: "Allen", checked: false }
  ]);

  const toggleCheck = (id) => {
    const checkedIdx = user.findIndex((u) => u.id === id);
    if (checkedIdx === -1) return;
    const updatedUser = [...user];
    updatedUser[checkedIdx].checked = !updatedUser[checkedIdx].checked;
    setUser(updatedUser);
  };

  const remove = () => {
    setUser([...user].filter((u) => !u.checked));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {Object.keys(user[0]).map((elm, i) => {
              return (
                <td key={i}>{elm.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + elm.slice(1)}</td>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {user.map((elem, ind) => {
            return (
              <tr key={elem.id}>
                <td>{elem.id}</td>
                <td>{elem.name}</td>
                <td>{elem.surname}</td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name=""
                    id=""
                    onChange={() => toggleCheck(elem.id)}
                    value={elem.checked}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button className="btn btn-primary ms-2" onClick={() => remove()}>
        Delete selected
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-field-hv6ebt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is the code to a working sandbox.

Comment: Just a genuine question here, doesn't the `setUser((oldUsers) => {
      oldUsers[index].checked = !oldUsers[index].checked;
      return oldUsers;
    });
  };
 mutate the state?

Comment: Thanks, this is how remove function works, but when click the checkbox in the browser, it does not show the selected checkbox, can fix it?

Comment: @Andrey My bad. I picked the wrong attribute, check the edited answer with the sandbox.

Comment: Another option with checkboxes:
` const toggleCheck = (elem) => {
    if(!elem.checked) {
      elem.checked = true;
    } else {
      elem.checked = false;
    }
    setUser([...user]);
  }`